# WordPress remove the_title by way of filter?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to remove the following code which is found within my WordPress template:

`<?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>`

I don't want to modify the template or do this via CSS.

I would like to do this in some way through the functions.php file.

Maybe something like this:
`add_filter( 'the_title', 'suppress_if_title_h1', 10, 2 );`

I just don't know what to do next?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title - you won't have access to whether it's an h1, the class, etc.

Comment: Is there no way to determine if it is h1, h2 or so on?

Comment: Correct. The filter has no "insight" into the markup, so there's no practical way.  If you're curious, check out the code for the `the_title` function in `wp-includes/post-template.php`.  The only thing that is filtered is the actual title, NOT the markup ($before / $after).

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. Looks like I'll need to simply comment it out of the template.

Answer (score 0):

I am not wrong you want to remove this `<?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>` code from your template file.

Yes, you can remove the below code from your template through function file by using the wp filter. Write a function like below -

```
function remove_post_title ( $title, $id = null ) {
    // This will remove the title from the post
    return '';
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'remove_post_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: The problem with your approach is that it renders ```the_title``` function useless. I only want to remove one specific call for the title. When the function receives those specific parameters ```( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' )```.